# WP Product Query that updates custom meta reached the memory limit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

The server has a memory limit of about 2000mb. That's pretty high, so I'm not sure if simply increasing that limit is the answer or not.

The script uses `get_posts` to iterate through all 100,000+ products, `get_the_terms` to get an attribute, and the biggest one is `update_post_meta` to update the meta field.

The main reason for the script is to assign a custom meta "priority_brand" to products based on the order set using an Advanced Custom Fields repeater. That way, someone can drag & drop a priority by brand order, and then on the front end I modify the query elsewhere to display those products based on that priority order.

The following script runs as a CRON:

```html
<?php
include '/path/to/wp-load.php';

echo "brand-priority";
error_log("brand-priority");


$brands = get_field("brands_order", "options");
$brand_IDs = array();
foreach ($brands as $brand) {
  array_push($brand_IDs, $brand['brand']);
}

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'fields' => 'ids',
);
$products = get_posts($args);

$i = 1; foreach ($products as $ID) {
  $brand = get_the_terms($ID, 'pa_brand');
  $brand = $brand[0] ?? false;
  if (!$brand) {
    continue;
  }

  $brand_ID = $brand->term_id;
  $priority = array_search($brand_ID, $brand_IDs) + 1;

  update_post_meta($ID, "priority_brand", $priority);
}
```

I'm not sure how else I can optimize this script. I'm already returning only the IDs to iterate through. I believe the biggest issue is the `update_post_meta` function, but I don't see how else I can update the meta more optimally.

UPDATE: I added `wp_suspend_cache_addition( true );` at the top of the script (after the error_log). Still the same issue persists.

Comment: I would try to split the 100.000+ products into chunks, and use AJAX to update the post meta - not sure how, but I think that it would help, since you can work with smaller amounts of data at a time.

Comment: I ended up adding wp_suspend_cache_addition( true ); at the top of the script after the include, and deactivated the W3 Total Cache plugin. I think that plugin was writing to cache on each meta update, which was increasing the memory usage. I tested with the plugin disabled and outputted the memory usage and noticed it was steady. The script worked fine.